Is there a way in Ansible to lookup content in a host file without using another Ansible module/task?
Background: I had a lineinfile module that was using regexp and line to ensure I have correct lines inside of my config files. This works perfectly but there is an issue that I did not think of, other people adding in the same line in the config file with a different setting. Ansible lineinfile only changes the last instance; In order to fix this, I created a function to handle all of the duplicates, so we only have one instance of that line in the file. I know that templating the files would be fast/optimal, but I am not allowed to do that... Below is the working code; inside of the roles/duplicate_checker/tasks/main.yml, I want to basically check to see if the line inside of the config_path is the same as the variable I am passing through (config_line).
What I want to be able to do: All I want is to be able to skip the last task in roles/duplicate_checker/tasks/main.yml if the line that I am tyring to change is the same as in the file.
roles/kyle/tasks/main.yml:
---
- name: Lineinfile handler
  include_role: 
    name: "roles/duplicate_checker"
  loop: "{{ lineinfile_facts }}"
  vars:
    config_name: "{{ item.name }}"
    config_path: "{{ item.path }}"
    config_regexp: '{{ item.regexp }}'
    config_line: "{{ item.line }}"
    config_stigid: "{{ item.stigid }}"
  when: item.when

- name: Notify handlers with assert
  assert: { that: true, quiet: true }
  changed_when: True
  when: True
  notify:
    - dconf_update
    - ssh_restart
    - auditd_restart

roles/kyle/defaults/main.yml:
lineinfile_facts:
  - name: 'Banner'
    stigid: 'V-230225'
    path: '/etc/ssh/sshd_config'
    regexp: '^\s*(?i)banner\s+'
    line: 'banner /etc/issue'
    when: True and "'openssh-server' in packages"
# I have like over 150 of these

roles/duplicate_checker/tasks/main.yml:
---
# This takes 4 seconds
- name: "{{ config_stigid }} Get the count of occurences in {{ config_path }}"
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ config_path }}"
    regexp: "{{ config_regexp }}"
    state: absent
  check_mode: true
  changed_when: false
  register: dupes
# This should be skipped most of the time, so I am not worried about this
- name: "{{ config_stigid }} Remove all occurences from {{ config_path }} if the count is greater than one"
  replace:
    path: "{{ config_path }}"
    regexp: "{{ config_regexp }}"
  when: 
    - dupes.found is defined
    - dupes.found > 1
# This takes 4 seconds, but I want to be able to skip it if the line in the file and the line in my variables, config_line are the exact same
- name: "{{ config_stigid }} {{ config_name }}"
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ config_path }}"
    line: "{{ config_line }}"
    regexp: "{{ config_regexp }}"
    create: true

What I tried: I tried to use ansible builtin lookups inside of the when condition of the task below but after a ton of errors I figured out that this only searches on the control node and I want it to search on the host.
- name: "{{ config_stigid }} {{ config_name }}"
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ config_path }}"
    line: "{{ config_line }}"
    regexp: "{{ config_regexp }}"
    create: true
  when: "{{ config_line not in lookup('file', config_path) }}"

